# bootbox : disappears behind calling dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this bootbox alert

```
bootbox.alert({
    message: "Relance envoyée",
   className:"on-top-bootbox-alert-2"
   },function(){
       vm.clear();
});
.on-top-bootbox-alert-2 {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

I have set this class because I am calling bootbox from a dialog box.
So the bootbox alert appears on top.

It works well if I don't add `function(){vm.clear()}`.
If I add the return function, the bootbox appears behind the dialog, and I can't see it.

Is it normal?

Comment: No one will be able to tell unless you read the following page and adjust your `code` accordingly: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
bootbox.alert({
    message: "Relance envoyée",
    className: "on-top-bootbox-alert-2",
    callback: function () {
            vm.clear();
    }
});
```